# extend root partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

[image: partition details]
I want to extend the `/dev/sda5` by 10Gb. For that I followed some blogs but now I have unallocated space created which I am unable to use to extend the `/dev/sda5`. From the unallocated space I tried to create new partition as well but I think that was not a good choice because my aim is to extend the other partition size and not to create a new one.

Can anyone guide me with simple steps to increase that partition size?

Comment: Some confusion which partition you want to increase -- sda5 is not your root partition (sda1 is).

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1015557/how-to-merge-unallocated-partition-to-linux-partition?newreg=31abf9eedc174fbb8ae219a613043c99)? Worked for me just the other day

Comment: @ubfan1: In `sda2` I have `sda5` and `sda6`. I do not have a good terminology on this but my intention is to add some of the unallocated space to `sda5`. Currently it is 36.57GiB and I want to make it around 40GiB.

Answer (score 0):

You have, MBR partitioning with one "straight" partition - /dev/sda1 - and an Extended partition.
To enlarge /dev/sda1 (your root partition) you need to move the Extended partition towards the end of the disk (right in the image shown by gparted).

The Extended partition contains your /home and /faisal partitions.

To Resize /dev/sda5 (your /home partition) you need to:

1. create a situation where the Extended partition covers the last "unallocated" space, increasing the "unallocated" space inside the extended partition (if possible),
2. then move /dev/sda6 into that unallocated space, so that the unallocated space appear between /dev/sda5 and /dev/sd6.
3. This situation will then allow /dev/sd5 to be enlarged.

*Note:

gparted allows you to define a set of operations,

then applies those as you click "the green tick".*